# Sort of UITableView data returns wrong data when row is selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with custom cells in a iPad app.  When I sort the array that is the data source for that `UITableView`, and I click on a row in the `UITableView`, the detail data for that row is wrong (I empty the selected row data into `UITextFields`)!  If I don't sort the array, the detail is correct!  Here is the code that sorts the datasource array:

```
-(void) reloadClientList: (BOOL *)dontDeleteKey  {

    custDataArray = [NSMutableArray new];  //Init Array to hold TableView Data

    if(boSortClientList.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)  {  //  sort alphabetically
        [custDataArray addObjectsFromArray: [ClientInfo MR_findAllSortedBy:@"aClientLastName" ascending:YES]];
    }
    else if(boSortClientList.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)  {  //  sort by phone number
        [custDataArray addObjectsFromArray: [ClientInfo MR_findAllSortedBy:@"aClientPrimaryPhone" ascending:YES]];
    }
    else  {  //  no sort
        [custDataArray addObjectsFromArray:[ClientInfo MR_findAll]];
    }

    [self.clientList reloadData];

    if(dontDeleteKey == false)
        selectedClientKey = nil;  // clear selectedClientKey
}
```

Why is this occurring?  What do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: show code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `didselectRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely your sorting the data in an array and using the sorted array in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Then in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you are using the unsorted array to get which detail page to go to. You should be able to fix your issue by using the sorted array in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Fantastic!  That was exactly the problem... thank you so much; I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you select a row, this code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` recreates the array once again:

```
custDataArray = [NSMutableArray new];
[custDataArray addObjectsFromArray:[ClientInfo MR_findAll]];
```

You need to perform a check whether or not your custDataArray is nil. If it's not nil then you don't need those lines.

Answer (score 1):

Create an ivar to hold your NSMutableArray.  You're sorting your array `reloadClientList`, but you're not using the same array in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.